# Processing a boolean in a class

Tags: c++, function, class, operator-keyword

I have a problem where I am trying to assign a fraction either Y or N for if it is positive and then when the fraction is printed out having the the appropriate sign for the function. I do not understand if I can pass the tempchar to the print function or how to make this print out correctly. Thank you all for your help

```
class fraction

{
    private:
        int numerator;
        int denom;
        bool positive;

    public:
        void inputFrac();
        void printFrac();

        fraction fracMult(fraction& b);
        fraction fracDiv(fraction& b);
        fraction fracAdd(fraction& b);
        fraction fracSub(fraction& b);
};

 void fraction::printFrac()
{
    if(!positive)
    {
    cout << "-";
    }
    cout << numerator << " / " << denom;
}
void fraction::inputFrac()
{    
    fraction tempchar;
    char tempchar1;

    cout<<"Please input the numerator ";
    cin>>numerator;
    cout<< "Please input the denominator ";
    cin>>denom;
    cout<<"Is the fraction positive? (Y or N) ";
    cin>>tempchar1;

    if(tempchar1=='Y')
    {
        positive=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the value of 'positive' depending on whether it is 'Y' or 'N'.  Your conditional in inputFrac() isn't updating the value.  Then, you can conditionally print a message with a '+' if its true, or a '-' if it is false.

*Edit:  Assuming your inputFrac() method works, you should only need the following:

```
void fraction::printFrac()
{
    if (!positive)
    {
        cout << "-" << numerator << " / " << denom;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "+" << numerator << " / " << denom;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind me asking what the code to do that would be?

Comment: What the answerer is saying is change 
`f(tempchar1=='Y') { positive; }` to `f(tempchar1=='Y') { positive = 1; }` - you need to assign a value to `positive`.

By the way, the variable `tempchar` is unused.

Comment: I did this as you suggested and it still does not work. Do you have any ideas as to why not?

Comment: Set the value of positive based on tempchar1, and change printFrac() to dynamically output the value.  Better yet, add a function to just grab the value of the string representation of positive.  You could do '+' or just an empty string when it is true, and '-' for false depending on your requirements!

Comment: how would i change my code in order to keep the print function the same but make it dynamic and working?

Comment: I checked my input fraction and the discrepency is coming from the print function, I am unable to transfer the positive value to the print function